# Generating Label and Switch from Json Request

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON response as follows in `Android Studio`

```
{"items":
 [{ 
  "username":"gadbe76p",
  "fname":"Ben",
  "lname":"Gadd",
  "jobtitle":"CSR"},
 ]}
```

How can I take that response and generate a Label and Switch, as to select that user or not for a function ?

I have no idea where to start.
Sorry for the lack of basic understanding, very new to Android Studio.

So Label would contain `fname` and `lname` with the switch of on/off for value of `username`.

Cheers

James

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

this link should help you and give you several examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse through the JSON object and place what you want parsed out into a variable then use that variable to set your labels

Comment: Able to offer any help with how to do that ?